# How to deploy a dynamic web project war file in heroku?

Tags: javascript, deployment, java, heroku

I am trying to deploy a war file in Heroku. Using Eclipse IDE, I developed a Dynamic Web Project which having basic HTML + JavaScript + j2ee files and the application is working well in my server (tomcat 7). While trying to deploy the same in Heroku I am getting this error : **"No access to this app"**. Is there any way to deploy the war file in Heroku.

This is the command I used : ***heroku deploy:war --war "E:\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat7-8080\webapps\MyApp.war" --app MyApp.v.1***

Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

The argument given as `--app` atribute is not your own app name. You should type there a name which was automatically generated by heroku. It is visible in your heroku panel. Eg. `stormy-apple-6978`